# Create a folder on Wildfly server using maven build and add properties file into it

Tags: maven, deployment, java-8, wildfly

I want to deploy an application into wildfly as war packaged using maven. The challenge i am facing is , i need to create a directory in the server and add my application's property file and a log4j property file into it. This must be automated using maven build.

First i need to know if this is possible to create a folder in server which is not the project home directory, but elsewhere using maven while deploying it ?

If so , how do i create it, and how to add the property files into it which is in my project resource folder.

Note: My deployment is automated through Jenkins.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just include the properties files in your deployment? Copying files to a remote server will likely not work.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins , We have a setup in server that we put all the property files in a folder with the name of the application.
Hence for a new application to deploy, there would be no directory with the name. So for every new deployment a directory will be created and property files are placed into it